# Coinbase Sandbox API Unauthorised API Key

Tags: java, spring-boot, coinbase-api

I have generated a number of API keys for coinbase sandbox and am trying to use them to get the list of user accounts. However I keep getting the same error 401 Unauthorised API key.

I have read through the documentation and am quite sure im doing everything right.

Below is my code. If anyone can see whats wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
        return args -> {

            // request url
            String url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts";

            long unixTime = Instant.now(clock).getEpochSecond();

            String sha256hex = Hashing.sha256()
                    .hashString("rv3fSnIVN5R0DzINY6RRAronuWLAxPLV48XnGOFP+WL8Lh22bOJ0BvwyGH37hZ2tLRuTsjSnGCmK/dDM9FKNcw==", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    .toString();

            // create headers
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.set("CB-ACCESS-KEY", "63d1342304ba4d7fcc1297bf26a90418");
            headers.set("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", sha256hex);
            headers.set("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP",""+unixTime);
            headers.set("CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE","xdeqz62oak");

            // build the request
            HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);


            ResponseEntity<LiveData> liveData = restTemplate.exchange(
                    url,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    request,
                    LiveData.class);
            log.info(liveData.toString());
        };
```